# Get instanced object by attribute

Tags: java, oop, object

Is it possible to refer to an instanced object by it's value in Java?

```
    Object one = new Object("A");
    Object two = new Object("B");

    method(Object.getByValue("A"));
```

Depending on the situation I'd like to pick a different object. Obviously all the objects have to have a different value, otherwise there is no way to tell which one.

Comment: You'll have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean your own class. There's no `Object(String)` constructor.

Yes, but not directly. You'll need to create a map. In this case, we'll use HashMap.
In `MyObject`, declare

```
static HashMap<String, MyObject> objects = new HashMap<>();
```

The constructor of `MyObject` will need to get a line added. Modify it to look like:

```
public MyObject(String stringParam);
    // existing constructor logic

    objects.put(stringParam, this); 
}
```

assuming `stringParam` is the constructor parameter you used.

You can then write a static method:

```
static MyObject getByValue(String s){ return objects.get(s); }
```

Comment: Wow, I was about to go down the rabbit hole into object reflection. Whoops! I guess there's a better way to do it after all.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

```
class MyObject {
    private static Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static MyObject createObject(String str) {
        MyObject newObj = new MyObject(str);
        map.put(str, newObj);
    }

    public static MyObject getObject(String str) {
        return map.get(str);
    } 

    private String name;

    public MyObject(String str) {
        this.name = str;
    }
}
```